# UICollectionView "flow direction"

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout

the typical flow for the UICollectionView is to "move across, then down"

[image]

I was curious if there was a way to reverse the order of the "flow" i.e go "down first" (for maximum rows, then across.) Similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Change the scroll direction of the flow layout to horizontal.

Comment: @rmaddy Given the second diagram, the request seems to be to keep the scroll direction vertical.

Answer (score 2):

> I was curious if there was a way to reverse the order of the "flow" i.e go "down first" (for maximum rows, then across.)

There's no way to get `UICollectionFlowLayout` to layout the cells in column-major order — it "flows" the cells across first, and then down. That makes sense if you think about it -- how would `UICollectionFlowLayout` know how many cells to place in the first column before starting the second? As it is, it just places as many as will fit in the row before moving to the next row. But since you want the scrolling direction to remain vertical, it wouldn't have any reason to stop adding cells to the first column.

But `UICollectionView` will happily put the cells wherever you like -- you just have to create your own custom layout object to tell it where to put them. That doesn't have to be as daunting as it might sound... laying out cells on a grid isn't rocket science, and your collection layout object doesn't have to be as robust as `UICollectionFlowLayout` is -- it only has to meet your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: it would be more easy to arrange the given data in column major order without implementing own flow layout.

Comment: @RatulSharker The number of columns is often not constant. The device might rotate, for example, or the user might split the screen between two apps.

Comment: Yes the number of column isn't constant, but it can be easily calculated. As far as the requirement is to create two row, just divide by two the total number of element will give you the number of column.

Comment: @RatulSharker Perhaps that should be an answer instead of a comment then.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Caleb for inspiring me. I tried the following setup

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let items = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

    // other unnecessary stuff for this demonstration
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return ((items.count + 1) / 2) // just ceiling, after dividing by 2
        } else  if section == 1 {
            return items.count - ((items.count + 1) / 2) // calculating the remainder item
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        var text = "";
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            // take the even part
            text = items[indexPath.row * 2]
        } else {
            // take the odd part
            text = items[(indexPath.row * 2) + 1]
        }

        (cell.subviews[0].subviews[0] as? UILabel)?.text = text

        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
}
```

I set the scroll direction to `vertical` and the output looks like. It will work both for odd number of item and even number of item.

[image: Output]

Clearly this isn't the OP is looking for. Here i've used two different sections, but OP want to make the zig-zag pattern within a section. That certainly not possible as @Caleb sorted out, without filling width wise we cannot go down in vertical direction.

Comment: If you had more data, you could certainly fake column-major order by rearranging the data. It doesn't seem to me that the OP specifically asked for two rows... he/she just wanted to fill the cells by advancing down columns instead of across rows. There's no question that this approach does that. I'd call it a quick and dirty solution — quick because it's less work up front than writing a layout class; dirty because it's going to cause problems at every step going forward because you're working against the framework. Example: to add or delete an item you have to invalidate the whole section.

Comment: OP should maintain a way how many row, even if he managed to maintain a custom flowlayout class. Replace 2's with the rows. Yes deleting a new cell require invalidating all the sections, which it is and OP hasn't asked for it. A solution isn't dirty unless it cannot cover the use cases effitiently.

Comment: Time == $$, so sometimes quick and dirty is fine. The nice thing about UICollectionViewLayout is that it separates the responsibility for arranging the cells from the other tasks. This approach breaks that design and makes the data source responsible for second-guessing what the layout will do, making your code less flexible and more fragile. If you have a column-major flow layout object, for example, you can easily change your collection by swapping in a different layout; this way, changing layouts means rewriting the data source. That may be fine – if you're willing to pay the price.